# Classification task - how to handle large data file?

Tags: classification, bigdata

I'm planning to construct a classification model for predicting New York taxi trip fare. The CSV-datafile for this is very large, containing 112 234 626 rows (ca 10 GB). I have managed to download this file to my computer's local disc but 
the further memory problems arise when I'm starting to use this file for parsing and model construction.

So, my questions are:

1. What is the optimal number of rows that I should take from this datafile for use in my task?
2. How should I take these rows to prevent low memory problems?
3. How should I take these rows so that it contains optimal sample of all the months. The file contains data of year 2018 and if I take the rows so that it contains only pre-specified number of rows then for example the dataframe may contain only data for January (but I want all months).

[2018 Yellow Taxi Trip Data](https://data.cityofnewyork.us/Transportation/2018-Yellow-Taxi-Trip-Data/t29m-gskq)

Comment: Thank for posting. Would you add some details such as output of file processing, software tool you want to use, computer hardware spec, some sample code you tried, and etc? It would help to understand situation better.

Answer (score 2):

With pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

dataset = pd.read_csv(path, chunksize=1000) #number of rows per chunk

for chunk in dataset:
    #process chunk etc
```

Answer (score 0):

1) The optimal number of rows to use is all rows. Why would you *want* to use anything less than everything?

2) That depends entirely on the programming language and/or framework that you're trying to use. If you're working in Python, you could look at Dask and see if that solves your problems.

3) If you want to sample and you want to include equal portions from all parts of the file (rather than, for example, just the first 1000 rows and nothing else), then you would loop over all the rows one by one and add a random number between 0 and 1 from a uniform distribution. If you want to select a random 1% of the data, you then drop all rows that have this number > 0.01.

Comment: Dask is indeed worth looking at. Or use a training method that supports a partial fit so the training can be done line by line.

Comment: Many algorithms by themselves support training bit by bit with part of the data (in batches), but the programming framework doesn't always allow it. For example, using Spark it's built in not to read all data at once, but using scikit-learn you are typically required to load everything. So Spark would be an option too, but it's probably more of a learning curve.